# Supercollider disagrees with profile short summary re: my reputation

Tags: bug, reputation, top-bar

They say a picture is worth a thousand words - or in this case, ±10, depending on if you ask the super-collider or the user summary in the top bar.

[image: Supercollider with 50,005 while the user summary in the top bar says 50,015 with the caption 'why the difference?']

The reason why I bring this up is that I've only had 35 points worth of reputation come in at the time of this writing - the last 25 were an accept and an up vote that happened within a few seconds / minutes of each other.  The *accept* is reflected in the super-collider, but the up vote is not.  That sort of divergence seemed odd enough to me that wrote up this report.

Things I have done:

- Cleared my cache
- Reloaded the page (x5)
- Navigated to other pages

Comment: http://shouldiblamecaching.com/

Comment: And the supercolider doesn't auto-update, your rep counter does. Did you try reloading the page? Clearing your cache?

Comment: @MartijnPieters - *chuckles* if that were the case I wouldn't worry - I did clear my cache and reload the page multiple spaced out times before posting the free-hand circles annotated picture here.

Comment: I'd wait a day; there are so many layers of caching and servers in the SE network; sometimes a cached value can get stuck somewhere for a while, until the next flush. And that happens every 24 hours anyway.

Comment: I'm fine with things being out-of-sync - but every other time this has happened it's caught up pretty fast.  In this case, an accepted answer *was* tallied but the ensuing up-vote (which happened around the same time) was *not*.  That's when I said "odd" and wrote up this post :-)

Comment: That kind of detail should really be part of your initial report here though. Otherwise you *will* get the assumptions and be told to reload and clear cache, etc. all the way to the snarky caching site. :-)

Comment: *Laughs* Understood - updating my question now :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Almost everything that appears on the top bar is cached to high heavens.

Why? Because it appears on every. single. page view.

In particular these two values are different because one comes from your current set of pinned sites, cached 10 minutes, the other is fetched from db once per page view.

---

A correction: yes, caching is possibly involved, but this bug is likely not due to that. It is due to realtime updates. Only the top reputation is updated in real time via push notification when reputation changes. We will fix this soon.